# Удаление текстов внутри тегов

Tags: html

Например, у меня много такого кода, и я хочу стереть все тексты внутри тегов. Как я могу сделать это? Есть какой-нибудь текстовой редактор или сайт для этого?

```
 <tr>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>
      <a href="6.html" target="_blank">Здесь идет текст</a>
  </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>
      <a href="12.html" target="_blank">Здесь идет текст</a>
  </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Да, речь идёт о редактировании HTML-файла.C редактором знаю как заменить, но таблицах тексты разные. Таблицы много и на каждом другой текст. Удалить каждого строка длиться сутками

Answer (score 1):

А если речь идёт всего лишь о редактировании HTML-файла, то вам достаточно любого редактора, который умеет делать поиск и замену с использованием регулярных выражений.

Answer (score 0):

хотелось бы знать какие именно тэги Вы хотите "опустошить"...если речь идёт о содержимом ячеек таблицы, то:

```
$(function(){
   $('tr td').empty();
 });
```

либо

```
 $(function(){
   $('tr td').clear();     
 });
```

PS(это jQuery)